# Date formula adding/subtracting 6 months

Tags: formula-field, administration

I have a formula checkbox to compare the Start date and end date. However I am getting #Error. Can you please help me here?

I am trying to achieve this req: **Start Date - 6 monhts < Today && End Date + 6months > Today**

```
DATE(
  YEAR(   Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR( ( MONTH ( Start_Date__c ) - 6 - 1 ) / 12 ),
  MOD( MONTH ( Start_Date__c ) + 2 - 1 + 
    IF( DAY ( Start_Date__c ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( Start_Date__c ) - 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1, 
      2, 28,
      4, 30,
      6, 30,
      9, 30, 
      11, 30,
      31 ), 1, 0 ), 12 ) + 1,
    IF( DAY( Start_Date__c ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( Start_Date__c ) - 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1,
      2, 28, 
      4, 30, 
      6, 30, 
      9, 30, 
      11, 30, 
      31 ), 
    1, DAY( Start_Date__c )
  )
)<today()&&
DATE(
  YEAR(  End_date__c ) + FLOOR( ( MONTH ( End_date__c) + 6- 1 ) / 12 ),
  MOD( MONTH ( End_date__c) + 2 - 1 + 
    IF( DAY ( End_date__c) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( End_date__c) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1, 
      2, 28,
      4, 30,
      6, 30,
      9, 30, 
      11, 30,
      31 ), 1, 0 ), 12 ) + 1,
    IF( DAY( End_date__c) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( End_date__c) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1,
      2, 28, 
      4, 30, 
      6, 30, 
      9, 30, 
      11, 30, 
      31 ), 
    1, DAY( End_date__c)
  )
)>today()
```

Comment: Why not just use something like 182 days and call it good? Is this formula really worth maintaining? And I see you aren't counting leap years, either, so you're already not completely accurate.

Comment: Looks like this works fine "Start_Date__c -180<today()&& End_date__c +180 >today()"